# Asp.net 3.0 IServiceProvider cannot inject

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.0

*sigh* This line in startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<IServiceProvider, ServiceProvider>();
```

Breaks my app, can't debug, just stops after saying that the build was successful.  No errors.  No exceptions.  If I comment out this line, all works again and the app runs.

Why is that happening?  The reason I want to inject IServiceProvider is because it is required by ActivatorUtilities and I'm using that in the BaseController to make it easy to validate like such:

```cs
public MyController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider) { }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    ValidateFor<MyValidator>(viewModel);

    if (!IsValid)
    {
         ... error stuff
    }

    return Ok("Success!");
}
```

And in the BaseController

```cs
protected IserviceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

public BaseController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
}

public void ValidateFor<TValidator>(object instance) where TValidator : IValidator
{
     // injected ServiceProvider here as a protected property of the base controller
     var validator = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TValidator>(ServiceProvider);

      var result = validator.Validate(instance);

      if (result.IsValid)
      {
            return;
      }

      ... process errors
}
```

## SOLUTION

The solution is to use `IServiceProvider` in the right way within the context of the controller.

So instead of:

```
var validator = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TValidator>(ServiceProvider);
```

Get rid of the dependency entirely in your controller and use this instead:

```
var validator = HttpContext.RequestServces.GetService<TValidator>();
```

Comment: Did you look at logs?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

No need to inject service provider since it can be accessed via the controller's `HttpContext` for the current request

```
public BaseController() {

}

public void ValidateFor<TValidator>(object instance) where TValidator : IValidator {
     // Access the service provider via the current request
     var validator = HttpContext.RequestServces.GetService<TValidator>();

      var result = validator.Validate(instance);

      if (result.IsValid) {
            return;
      }

      //... process errors
}
```

Alternatively the whole service locator approach can be avoided by explicitly injecting the desired service into the action using the `[FromServices]` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(MyViewModel viewModel, [FromServices] MyValidator validator) {
    ValidateFor(validator, viewModel);
    if (!IsValid) {
         //... error stuff
    }
    return Ok("Success!");
}
```

Where the base `ValidateFor` can be refactored accordignly

```
protected void ValidateFor<TValidator>(TValidator validator, object instance) 
    where TValidator : IValidator {
    var result = validator.Validate(instance);

    if (result.IsValid) {
        return;
    }

    //... process errors
}
```

#### Reference [Dependency injection into controllers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection)

Comment: Works great.  On a previous project asp.net core 2.0, the previous paradigm was working.  However this pattern where you inject the validator directly into the controller method is great too.

Comment: However I will say that `ValidateFor<TValidator>(instance);` does seem cleaner.